# Is there a semantic html tag for short, descriptive fragments of text?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Let's say I'm writing markup to describe a book with a few lines of details, for example:

**A Tale of Two Cities**

- Author: Charles Dickens
- Year published: 1859
- Genre: Historical Fiction
- Average Review: 3.8/5

Here's the catch: Even though I've formatted it as a list in the example, it's not *semantically* a list. Also, many of these fields will be user-configurable, so the markup to books, authorship, and time don't really apply. Do I use `<p>`, `<li>`, `<dl>`, `<div>` or something else for each of these lines? If I don't fall back to `<div>`, the `<p>` tag seems the closest to what I want, even though it's not a complete paragraph of text.

What's the right tag for these non-list, not-quite-paragraph items whose keys and values I won't know until runtime?

Comment: re-reading this i may have misunderstood the question, are you asking for what to use for the entire book, or what to use for the book details?

Comment: I'm asking which tag to use for each of the lines of book details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you could consider the description list: `<dl>`

> The HTML  element (or HTML Description List Element) encloses a list of pairs of terms and descriptions. Common uses for this element are to implement a glossary or to display metadata (a list of key-value pairs).

```
<dl>
  <dt>Firefox</dt>
  <dd>A free, open source, cross-platform, graphical web browser
  developed by the Mozilla Corporation and hundreds of volunteers.</dd>
  <dd>The Red Panda also known as the Lesser Panda, Wah, Bear Cat or Firefox,
  is a mostly herbivorous mammal, slightly larger than a domestic cat
  (60 cm long).</dd>

<!-- other terms and definitions -->
</dl>
```

[More information available here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl)

Comment: In skimming all the MDN descriptions for tags, I failed to read this to the point where it said *metadata*, which is clearly what's being marked up. I'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [`dl` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) can be used for this purpose. The spec defines that it represents "an association list" (or "description list") that consists of "name-value groups".

Your case is similar to the third example in the HTML5 spec, as your content is also metadata:

> The following example illustrates the use of the `dl` element to mark up metadata of sorts. At the end of the example, one group has two metadata labels ("Authors" and "Editors") and two values ("Robert Rothman" and "Daniel Jackson").
>
> ```
> <dl>
>  <dt> Last modified time </dt>
>  <dd> 2004-12-23T23:33Z </dd>
>  <dt> Recommended update interval </dt>
>  <dd> 60s </dd>
>  <dt> Authors </dt>
>  <dt> Editors </dt>
>  <dd> Robert Rothman </dd>
>  <dd> Daniel Jackson </dd>
> </dl>
> ```